# Windows client can't connect to vsftpd server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ftp, gnutls

I've a problem about vsftpd server. I've created an vsftpd server with implicit ssl. It works perfectly with filezilla client on ubuntu 10.04, but when I run with filezilla client on windows, it got an error. The error was "GnuTLS error -12: A TLS fatal alert has been received."

This is the content of my vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_enable=YES
implicit_ssl=YES
listen_port=990
force_local_data_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
strict_ssl_read_eof=YES
```

Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Try to comment `implicit_ssl` option and restart service.

```
#implicit_ssl=YES
```

"If  enabled,  an  SSL handshake is the first thing expect on all connections (the FTPS protocol). To support explicit SSL  and/or plain  text  too,  a  separate vsftpd listener process should be run."
[Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html)

Comment: Sorry for long time reply. I've tried it, but give me same result. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

vsftpd uses DES-CBC3-SHA by default which is not supported by Filezilla. Add the line

```
ssl_ciphers=high
```

to vsftpd.conf to solve the problem.